# Jquery Conflict?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I am trying to use a jquery in my application where i have already used some jqueries before at several locations. how ever now i want to ad one more for my tab presentation. I am practicing it like this..

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js">
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $( "#my_tabs" ).tabs({
                event: "mouseover" //click 
            });
            $.noConflict();
        });
    </script>
```

But when i use this my previous jquery that i have used with another part of the same page stop working. I think the 2 jqueries have conflicts. I tried to do it with $.noConflict() as shown in above code and its not working I think that I am missing Something. Please help ...

Comment: Are you including jquery multiple times on a single page? If yes, why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how your code should be:

```
<script>
    var jq = $.noConflict();

    jq(function() {
        jq( "#my_tabs" ).tabs({
            event: "mouseover" //click 
        });            
    });
</script>
```

Or alternatively,

```
(function( $ ){
    $( "#my_tabs" ).tabs({
       event: "mouseover" //click 
    });            
})( jQuery );
```

The later is known as self-invoking anonymous function and used to map `$` to `jQuery` object which means you can use `$` inside safely.

Comment: Actually, there is a third, better way: `jq(function($) {  /* your code using $ here */ });` - the document.ready function always receives the jQuery object as its first argument

Answer (score 1):

```
var JQN = jQuery.noConflict();
```

usage example:

```
JQN("#id");
```